# Can VIM uncompress gzip files automatically with a different file extension?

Tags: vim, gzip

Vim automatically expands `.gz` files when I open them up, which is great.  However, it doesn't reccognize `.GZ` (upper case) in the same way.  Unfortunately I cannot change the file extensions of the files I'm working with for various reasons.  Is there a realatively simple way to register with VIM that `.GZ` are the same as `.gz` files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this into your .vimrc :

```
 augroup gzip
 au BufReadPre     *.GZ setlocal bin
 au BufRead        *.GZ call gzip#read("gzip -dn")
 au BufWritePost   *.GZ call gzip#write("gzip")
 au FileAppendPost *.GZ call gzip#write("gzip")
 au FileAppendPre  *.GZ call gzip#appre("gzip -dn")
 au FileReadPost   *.GZ call gzip#read("gzip -dn")
 au FileReadPre    *.GZ setlocal bin
 au FileWritePost  *.GZ call gzip#write("gzip")
 augroup END
```

If you want to know what autocmds were already activated for gz files you could have done:

```
:redir @x
:au
:redir END
"xp
/\.gz
```

This shows that gzip-related autocmds are in the gzip group. Then `:au gzip` gives a more compact list.

Reference:

```
:help :autocmd
:help :augroup
```

Original autocmds are in plugin/gzip.vim in your vim runtime. You can tell that with `:verbose au gzip`

Comment: good idea about the augroup. Don't forget the `bin` option, though

Comment: @sehe: updated answer with full list of autocmds (for new buffers without existing files also, and how to get the list yourself)

Comment: It works after one small modification.  I had to change the group name `gzip`.  (I picked `gzip_upper`, I'm guessing that this was conflicting with the existing `gzip` group?)... I've used VIM for a long time, but never delved into the guts of it.  I didn't know where to start.  Thanks a bunch!  You guys are fast! This issue has been bugging me for years!